# Send text from flutter to node js

Tags: node.js, flutter, http

When i press a butoon i just want to send some text from flutter to my node js app.

I want to send "text2" to a node js app using http.dart

When i press my raised button i want it to send an http string with the variable text 2 to a node js app.

i'd like to get a link of a tutorial do that or just some help, bc i don't find anything on the web, thx.

My flutter code :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

var text2;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Bot Discord App',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        primaryColor: const Color(0xFF2196f3),
        accentColor: const Color(0xFF2196f3),
        canvasColor: const Color(0xFFfafafa),
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}


class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Bot Discord App'),
      ),
      body:
      new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            new SizedBox(
              width: 100.0,
              height: 100.0,
              child:
              new Padding(
                child:
                new Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text(
                        "Precense",
                        style: new TextStyle(fontSize:19.0,
                            color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                            fontFamily: "Roboto"),
                      ),

                      new TextField(
                        style: new TextStyle(fontSize:12.0,
                            color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                            fontFamily: "Roboto"),
                      )
                    ]

                ),

                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              ),

            ),

            new SizedBox(
              width: 100.0,
              height: 50.0,
              child:
              new Padding(
                child:
                new RaisedButton(key:null,
                    onPressed: () {
                      return
                        text2 = Text(myController.text) as String;
                    },
                    color: const Color(0xFFe0e0e0),
                    child:
                    new Text(
                      "UPDATE",
                      style: new TextStyle(fontSize:23.0,
                          color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                          fontFamily: "Roboto"),
                    )
                ),

                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6.0, 6.0, 7.0, 6.0),
              ),

            )
          ]

      ),

    );
  }
  void buttonPressed(){}

}
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49914136/how-to-integrate-flutter-app-with-node-js

Comment: You can also take a look at socket.io https://socket.io/ and dart package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_socket_io if you want to make a chat app. There are plenty of socketio tutorials online.

Comment: I just want a simple code that send a string to an ip it's all

Comment: Here is a flutter Http Post example. You can send data this way: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data . create a post route in your nodejs server and use this code to make a request.